# Facebook Share Button with Database Driven Site

Tags: facebook

I have a couple questions regarding using Social Plugins for my website, specifically a share button.

I would like my site visitors to have the ability to share a product they find during a search so that the image of the product and the query string URL is shared. Don’t know if this is possible.

My content is database driven and uses query strings. The product image is also database driven, as the image sits in a SQL database and is not in a file directory.

My product details query string looks like this: http://www.example.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ID=97

Help/Suggestions appreciated. I am new to Facebook development.

Thanks